# Rigging is not working in one Area, it has no affect on the mesh. Other areas fine

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

I am focusing on character animation this week, and have a object that was not rigged in Blender files.  So I decided to rig it myself.

I had great success on MOST of the body.  However the mouth area is not working properly.

I did a re-rigging using Rigafy, and still no movement.  Everything else works as expected.

I am attaching the Blender file as well.  Normally I end up answering my own questions, but this one has me stymied.

[image]

[image: The selected regions have no affect on the mesh]

Comment: Have you used "Parent with Automatic Weights"? The lips work with this. You just need to add 4 bones at the bottom of the eye to limit the lip bone's influence.

Comment: Okay when I first set up the rig, I used Parent with automatic weights.  However, you did something that worked (thank you).  I can add 4 bones at the bottom (what should they be added from).

In addition, you suggest parenting.  what do I use as the lip bones parent?  I will play around, but then look at your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thank you Blunder for pointing me in the right direction.

The issue is I added the lips and what-not AFTER I did the original parenting of armature to mesh.

I assumed (incorrectly) that generating rig would reparent. It did not. Reapplying the rig using rigafy did not, as I thought, recreate the parenting.  I needed to do both.  I will figure out the extra bones shortly.  Thanks.